# ZedGraphControl does not Auto Zoom to use all of GraphPane

Tags: zedgraph

I am using `ZedGraphControl` but cannot seem to use the full GraphPane.  There are gray padding areas on each side of X-Axis.  I have set the following, but it does no good.

```
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;

myPane.YAxis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
myPane.YAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;

myPane.Y2Axis.Scale.MinAuto = true;
myPane.Y2Axis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but maybe try setting the following properties on your ZedGraph control

```
  zedGraphControl1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((
        System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
  zedGraphControl1.AutoSize = true;
  zedGraphControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
  zedGraphControl1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response -- I tried that too, but did not work either.  I was hoping this was going to be easy, but has been a major logjam.  Look here: http://www.guilhermemorais.com/blog/?tag=line-vertical  I wanted my chart to look like this -- no Padding on each side of the Graph.  I would like to add a picture of mine, however, I do not have authorization yet.  Thanks,

Comment: Would you have a picture of what your graph looks like with the problematic gray areas?

Comment: I cannot upload pics, not authorized, however, look here: http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/index3d29.html?title=Line_With_Band_Demo  You can see each side of the graph has a blanked out area.  The lines do not extend to the edge of the Pane

Comment: I see, you might need to specify zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min and zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max to be the min and max x values of your data set

Comment: Not the best way to run a railroad, however, this works..  except the when pressing "Default" it takes you back to the Padding.  I can probably just get rid of the Padding menu item...  Thanks.. 
   double min = myPane.CurveList[0].Points[0].X;
   double max = myPane.CurveList[0].Points[myPane.CurveList[0].Points.Count - 1].X;
   myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = min;
   myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = max;

Comment: I was going to place a "vote up" for you, but, not authorized.. thanks.